# Media queries are removing social button icon images

Tags: php, css, wordpress, media-queries

I am working on a project to make a WordPress instance more responsive and what I did was create a stylesheet specific to mobile devices and implemented a media query to use it. However, there is a problem. The problem is that on the non-mobile version there are two social media icons ( twitter & facebook) and there is also a 'go to top' icon with an arrow in it. When my mobile theme is used all three of these icons disappear. The containers they are in are still active and present, and you can click on them and get the correct result, but the image icons are gone. I am not sure how to fix this as I've been fiddling about for a few hours now.

These two links are the before and after of what I'm working on. Any help is appreciate.
Thank you

To see the affect you would need to collapse the browser to mobile dimensions and scroll down until you see the social media icons.

Before:
http://projectplay.wpengine.com/

After:
http://projectplay.staging.wpengine.com/

Comment: check if the mobile.css and style.css are in the same folder, apparently path cannot be found

Comment: Thanks. I got so tunnel visioned that I was poking around the elements panel of the chrome debugger instead of looking at the obvious....the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the mobile.css and style.css are NOT in the same folder,so apparently the path to the image cannot be found

Answer (score 0):

`social_icons.png` does not exist on the 'after' site.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It does. The social button icon images disappear on the after site. That is a direct result of `social_icons.png` not being located on the after site.